# Image exceeding parent size

Tags: css, image, height

I want to center and restrict an image
I have an outer `container` and an `image-container` which has `display: inline-block;` to have the same size as the image (required, will contain draggable items)
But the image keeps exceeding the `height: 100%;`
Is there a workaround to get the desired result (as in the screenshot)
[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-container { 
  display: inline-block;
  background: #0f0;
  outline: 5px solid #00f;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  
}

.main-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="main-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j32wb3nL/2/)

Comment: It's a design panel that will contain an image and some draggable items. It should work on various screen sizes, hence the "strange" scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using absolute positioning on the `image-container` to collapse it to the size of the child. this requires `position: relative` on the parent container. `overflow: hidden` is added here to fix slight offset due to the transform on `image-container`.

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

`position`, `top`, `left`, and `transform` are set here to center the `image-container` vertically and horizontally in the parent container.

```
.image-container {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

`max-width` and `max-height` need to match the parent container's width and height.

```
.main-image {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j32wb3nL/22/)

Comment: I wanted `image-container` to have the same size as the image. That's because it will contain draggable elements and I have to save their location without dealing with the offset. I'm now guessing it's not possible

Comment: sorry, missed that clause of your question

Comment: Thank you, I should've emphasized it

Comment: try this: it's not perfect, but it's really close: https://jsfiddle.net/j32wb3nL/21/

Comment: I might use your solution and make it dynamic using some js. Please edit your answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

.image-container { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal centering */
  background: #0f0;
  outline: 5px solid #00f;
}

img { /* responsiveness */
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="main-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400">
  </div>
</div>
```